# How does a component in nextjs do so that its value comes from an api

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm starting my React studies and trying to create a title component and a description component (paragraph), but I'm facing challenges. Here's the data that comes from the API:

[image: API Data]

### Component Code

```js
// use client
import { PersonalitiesProps } from "@/@types/personalities";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Personalities = () => {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState<PersonalitiesProps | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/personalidades", {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        });
        const result = await res.json();
        console.log(result);
        setApiData({ data: result });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log(apiData);
  return (
    <section>
      {apiData && apiData.data && apiData.data.map(nomes => (
        <div key={nomes.nome}>
          <h1>{nomes.nome}</h1>
        </div>
      ))}
      {apiData && apiData.data && apiData.data.map(personalidades => (
        <div key={personalidades.id}>
          <h2>{personalidades.nome}</h2>
          <p>{personalidades.historia}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </section>
  );
};

export default Personalities;
```

what I'm calling it on the page:

```
import Personalities from "@/components/Personalities";

export default function TestePage() {
  return (
    <section>
      <Personalities />
    </section>
  );
}
```

Information
Nextjs: 14.x
TypeScript: Yes
API: Golang (local)
NextJs: APP/ROUTER

Comment: Can you state the problem more clearly?